# Adding a certificate as a http request header in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to add a certificate as a request header in one of the api calls to a 3rd party tool that we are using. Is there any way to access the certificate stored in certificate and key management store?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are used as part of the Transport layer. You do not set them as HTTP Request Headers. You can read more about it in [Using Certificates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs.htm). To use a specific certificate, you simply call setClientCertificateName:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setClientCertificateName('DocSampleCert');
```

Comment: yes but the tool I'm using is looking for the certificate in request headers, is there anyway I can save the certificate in a custom setting and get it in apex?

Comment: @RushiJoshi Store certificate in Static Resource, SOQL in your code to get that and put it in header as Base64String

Comment: @RushiJoshi A custom setting won't have enough space for a certificate. You could store it as Custom Metadata instead.